# Ubuntu 16.04 does a swap partition cause Bad magic number in super-block

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, swap

I have problems with my internal hard drive so I now boot from an external 1TB drive.  It is normally identified as sdb but currently for file system checking I am booting from a LiveCD memory stick so the external drive appears as sdc.  It is partitioned as sdc1 97GB ext4 on /, sdc2 4GB swap, sdc3 585GB ext4, sdc4 243GB ext4.  Running fsck /dev/sdc gives following error:-

```
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdc
```

fsck returns clean when I fsck each partition individually except swap.  Example for sdc1 below, same for sdc3 and 4.

```
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
/dev/sdc1: clean, 1069686/6406144 files, 11807341/25600000 blocks
```

but swap partition just returns

```
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
```

my question is do I have a file system problem or is it just because I have a swap partion or is it because my swap partition is sdc2, if it is a file system error how do I fix it, do I need to do anything or is system ok - thanks guys

Comment: Your file systems appear to be clean, the swap-partition does not have a file system (this is normal). You will have another problem not related to the file systems.

Comment: @mook765 - thanks - how do I identify this problem

Comment: I don't know that, you didn't describe any problem yet. You got this messages due to the wrong commands (`fsck /dev/sdc`,`fsck/dev/sdc2`). `dev/sdc` is not a partition, it is the whole device, `dev/sdc2` is not an Ext-partition, it is the swap partition. The messages you got are normal for this cases. You say you have problems with your internal drive but you check the file systems on the external drive. What is your problem with the internal drive?

Comment: @mook765 - I did describe my problem.  I was worried about a message that said bad magic number in superblock and superblock invalid.  But according to you this is because the swap partition does not have a file system and this is normal.  I don't understand why you say I have another problem.  My internal drive returns a SMART error constantly, every time I boot so now I am booting from external and to be safe I wanted to check it was ok

Comment: The file systems on your external drive really seems to be ok, there is nothing to worry about and nothing to do. With the internal drive I guess we can't help much, sounds like the drive should be replaced with a new one.